# Why array dont concat with other array(by assignment, I can't use Array.flat method)

Tags: javascript

I have

```js
const flat = function(arr, n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return arr;
  } else if (n == 1) {
    let newarr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (Number.isInteger(arr[i])) {
        newarr.push(arr[i])
      } else if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
        newarr.concat(arr[i]) //look here
      } 
    }
    return newarr
  }
};

console.log(flat([2,4,[2,4,9],1,6],1))
```

that is, if I call a function with values

```
([2,4,[2,4,9],1,6],1)
```

I should get the answer

```
2,4,2,4,9,1,6
```

but I get

```
2,4,1,6
```

that is, without an array inside the array

Comment: change that line to `newarr = newarr.concat(arr[i])}`

Comment: `[2,4,[2,4,9],1,6].flat()` will do that for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array.concat returns a new array. You will either need to reassign the array (bad) or use something like the spread operator.

```
newarr.push(...arr[i])
```

**Edit**

I like @mplingjan comment. Array.flat could be a good choice here.

```
const flat = function (arr, n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return arr;
    } else if (n == 1) {
        let newarr = []
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            newarr.push(...Array.of(arr[i]).flat())             
        }
        return newarr
    }
};
```

Comment: Or `const flat = (arr, n)  => arr.flat(n);`; LOL

Comment: @angel.bonev something to do with `n` :P

Comment: flat(0) must return the same array as the`n==0 return arr` do , so basically the same function without the recursion. I think the OP will figured out eventually that he need recursion , `const arr2 = [0, 1, 2, [[[3, 4]]]];console.log(arr2.flat(3)); console.log(flat(arr2 , 1))`. will give different results

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it recursively.

newarr.push(...flat(arr[i]))

Comment: and don't forget `n-1` ;)